# How to return type based on array fields type

Tags: typescript

```
const record = await OrderModel.read(1003, [
  'id', 
  'billing_name',
]);
##record type object should provide record.id or record.billing_name only
```

the `OrderModel` class already has a generic `OrderType` (`T`) with all the fields available in that table.

What I'm trying to do is infer the type of `record` with only the keys defined in the second argument (`fields`).

Currently, all keys of `OrderType` are available and I can't seem to implement the `Pick` utility correctly to get the correct type returned.

```
// from OrderModel.ts
  public async read(id: number, fields: (keyof T)[] = [])
  {
    const result = await this.database.read<T, typeof fields>(id, this.tableName, fields);
    return result;
  }

// from database adaptor (this.database above)
  public async read<T, K extends (keyof T)>(id: number, tableName: string, fields: K[]): Promise<Pick<T, K>>
  {
    return this.connection(tableName).select(fields).where('id', id).first();
  }
```

```
// OrderType
export interface OrderModel {
  id: number;
  billing_name: string;
  billing_email: string;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the same generic type logic as your adapter `read` method, in the `OrderModel` version. Try something like this:

```
// notice generic and argument here, as well as return type
public async read<K extends keyof T>(id: number, fields: K[] = []): Promise<Pick<T, K>>
  {
    // notice type change below
    const result = await this.database.read<T, K>(id, this.tableName, fields);
    return result;
  }
```

See example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeUD2A7CAuK6CuAtgEYQBOANFMAO6o4DOwpAlugOZQC+AsAFB8B6AVABmpVASgB5UgBMyAWVTyANgDpg9PgEN6IdAGNReQ8GYYopCNtkBGADwBpKBAAewCOln0oAawggqCKwAHwAFMyyOPjEZJQizBAq3jiOANoAughQmQCUOAAK4gTM9BD2BcwGvvYwlI4hIch8UK1QBhiMlhD0eCrA2drU2swDVjYATLX14ZGUAOTA2kQqEABy2gQQ8-GJyfS5ANwtbVbAeKTo3b39x7w8-LxCosVQstpLRLrQNtpgwKhSFAwsAABalNTvT7fKDLVAANwguR0ekMxlM5iu41kUzqUGcbg8Xh8YX8gWCMFysyiuEIJAoVGWqw2WwYTFYbF2SRS+LyhWKpXKlWq03xjWavDa3XOl2QnFhPm06BAfAegmEBlBEGqVHA0A6BDAqzMFhIKlQ1D4fGxtjCtgmAGZKGlFrR5hlchotegwmErAcEE0Ouh6KhVmpzWw-T0NLRcrkoM95hhtlBSrhUAMlWh-pioFqrEA), I had to make some changes in order not to implement all the classes, but the gist is the same

**Side note:** Since you are directly passing the promise, no need to return/await it separately, just return it immediately:

```
public async read<K extends keyof T>(id: number, fields: K[] = []): Promise<Pick<T, K>>
  {
    return this.database.read<T, K>(id, this.tableName, fields);
  }
```